# Ruby hash.each behavior

Tags: ruby, hash

I have the following data:

```
contact_data = [["joe@email.com", "123 Main st.", "555-123-4567"],
            ["sally@email.com", "404 Not Found Dr.", "123-234-3454"]]

contacts = {"Joe Smith" => {}, "Sally Johnson" => {}}
```

and I'm trying to get it to this:

```
{
"Joe Smith"=>{:email=>"joe@email.com", :address=>"123 Main st.", :phone=>"555-123-4567"},
"Sally Johnson"=>{:email=>"sally@email.com", :address=>"404 Not Found Dr.",  :phone=>"123-234-3454"}
}
```

Here is the code I wrote:

```
contact_data = [["joe@email.com", "123 Main st.", "555-123-4567"],
            ["sally@email.com", "404 Not Found Dr.", "123-234-3454"]]

contacts = {"Joe Smith" => {}, "Sally Johnson" => {}}
data_hash = {}

counter = 0
contacts.each do |contact, value|
  data_hash[:email] = contact_data[counter][0]
  data_hash[:address] = contact_data[counter][1]
  data_hash[:phone] = contact_data[counter][2]
  counter += 1
  contacts[contact] = data_hash
end

p contacts
```

During the last iteration, new data_hash replaces both values. Why does this happen? I thought it is supposed to only replace the value of the current key.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's worth noting that keying on name is generally a bad idea as names are not necessarily unique. This may be just test code, but it's worth keeping that in mind as it's a bad habit to get into.

Answer (score 2):

When you want to iterate through two [Enumerable](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html) data structures at the same time, use [`zip`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-zip).

```
# Iterate through both the Array and the Hash together.
contact_data.zip(contacts.keys) { |data, name|
  # Turn the data into key/value pairs, then into a Hash.
  # Assign it to the proper spot in contacts.
  contacts[name] = [:email,:address,:phone].zip(data).to_h
}
```

This is basically the same as [Rajagopalan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62614096/14660), but I find it a bit easier to follow, and it modifies the original `contacts` Hash.

Answer (score 1):

The two answers posted so far rely on `zip`. Here's one that doesn't.

```
contacts.each_with_index.with_object({}) do |((name,_),i),h|
  email, address, phone = contact_data[i]
  h[name] = { email: email, address: address, phone: phone }
end
  #=> {"Joe Smith"=>{:email=>"joe@email.com",
  #      :address=>"123 Main st.", :phone=>"555-123-4567"},
  #    "Sally Johnson"=>{:email=>"sally@email.com",
  #      :address=>"404 Not Found Dr.", :phone=>"123-234-3454"}}
```

`zip` is needed when the size of the arrays being zipped is variable. If the size is known and small, however, it may be clearer to simply enumerate their elements.

This question relies on the keys of `contacts` being in a particular order. While Ruby maintains key-insertion order for hashes (and I have found situations where that can be used to advantage), I question whether that is good programming practice here. It would make more sense, I think, to make `contacts` the array `["Joe Smith", "Sally Johnson"]`.

Comment: Both other answers focus on giving the OP a new way to attack the problem, but as I see that's not the question.

Comment: @SebastianPalma, if you are referring to my last paragraph, it is just a consideration.

Answer (score 0):

```
contact_data = [["joe@email.com", "123 Main st.", "555-123-4567"],
                ["sally@email.com", "404 Not Found Dr.", "123-234-3454"]]

contacts = {"Joe Smith" => {}, "Sally Johnson" => {}}
```

Code

```
p contacts
      .keys
      .zip(contact_data
               .map {|h|[:email,:address,:phone].zip(h)}
               .map(&:to_h))
      .to_h
```

output

```
{"Joe Smith"=>{:email=>"joe@email.com", :address=>"123 Main st.", :phone=>"555-123-4567"}, "Sally Johnson"=>{:email=>"sally@email.com", :address=>"404 Not Found Dr.", :phone=>"123-234-3454"}}
```